# How to combine two xml file use xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two XML files and I need to go through XSL to mix the contents of these two files and output them to XML.

**trasactions.xml**

The transactions.xml file contains the transaction data, where the book information of the transaction is associated by bookid.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<transactions>
    <transaction>
        <shopId>1</shopId>
        <date>2022/01/21</date>
        <bookId>1</bookId>
        <value>25.5</value>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <shopId>1</shopId>
        <date>2022/01/22</date>
        <bookId>2</bookId>
        <value>25.5</value>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <shopId>2</shopId>
        <date>2022/01/21</date>
        <bookId>3</bookId>
        <value>25.5</value>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <shopId>2</shopId>
        <date>2022/01/22</date>
        <bookId>4</bookId>
        <value>25.5</value>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <shopId>2</shopId>
        <date>2022/01/23</date>
        <bookId>12</bookId>
        <value>25.5</value>
    </transaction>
</transactions>
```

**book.xml**

The book.xml file stores information about this book.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<books>
    <book>
        <title>C++</title>
        <bookId>1</bookId>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>C#</title>
        <bookId>2</bookId>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Java</title>
        <bookId>3</bookId>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Python</title>
        <bookId>4</bookId>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>XML</title>
        <bookId>5</bookId>
    </book>
</books>
```

**output.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<transactions>
    <shop shopID="1">
        <date time="2022/01/21">
            <title>C++</title>
            <value>25.5</value>
        </date>
        <date time="2022/01/22">
            <title>C#</title>
            <value>25.5</value>
        </date>
    </shop>
    <shop shopID="2">
        <date time="2022/01/21">
            <title>Java</title>
            <value>25.5</value>
        </date>
        <date time="2022/01/22">
            <title>Python</title>
            <value>25.5</value>
        </date>
    </shop>
</transactions>
```

If the bookid is not found in the book.xml file, delete the data.

**XSLT version=1.0**

Comment: The answers here - both regarding the grouping and the lookup from another document - depend on the version od XSLT you can use. In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, XSLT version is 1.0.@michael.hor257k

Comment: Well, then start by [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), then see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439555/xslt-1-0-value-look-up-map/32440143#32440143), for example, how to lookup from another document.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm so sorry. I'm new to XSLT, something I can't understand, can you give me a complete example?

Comment: If by "give complete example" you mean "write my code for me" then no.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I mean can you give me a link to the full example so I can learn how to solve my problem based on the example code. I'm not asking you to write the code for me. :(

Comment: I gave you a link to the article on Muenchian grouping that includes examples. And I gave you a link to an example of lookup from another document. I am afraid I cannot help you further until you post your own code.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Ok, thank you so much. I am now starting to learn this knowledge.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I know how to group shop use key, but I don't know how to group date  in shop tag? This is my code https://gist.github.com/weijiang1994/7797e16d59db30f039d447eed2be97ff

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete xslt that does what you need.

Some notes:

1. Script assumes that xml files `transactions.xml` and `books.xml` are in the same folder with the xslt file.
2. The entry point is here: `<xsl:template name="main">`, thus you have to apply it in an appropriate manner.

```xslt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"  />
    
    <xsl:variable name="transactions" select="document('transactions.xml')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="books" select="document('books.xml')"/>
    
    <xsl:template name="main">
        <transactions>
            <xsl:for-each select="$transactions/transactions/transaction[not(./shopId=preceding::shopId)]">
                <shop>
                    <xsl:variable name="shopId" select="./shopId"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="shopID"><xsl:value-of select="$shopId"/></xsl:attribute>
                    
                    <xsl:for-each select="$transactions/transactions/transaction[shopId = $shopId]">
                        
                        <xsl:variable name="bookId" select="./bookId"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="book" select="$books/books/book[bookId = $bookId]"/>
                                                
                        <xsl:if test="$book">
                            <date>
                                <xsl:attribute name="time">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="./date"/>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                                <title>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$book/title"/>
                                </title>
                                <value>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="./value"/>
                                </value>
                            </date>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>                    
                </shop>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </transactions>
    </xsl:template>    
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transactions>
   <shop shopID="1">
      <date time="2022/01/21">
         <title>C++</title>
         <value>25.5</value>
      </date>
      <date time="2022/01/22">
         <title>C#</title>
         <value>25.5</value>
      </date>
   </shop>
   <shop shopID="2">
      <date time="2022/01/21">
         <title>Java</title>
         <value>25.5</value>
      </date>
      <date time="2022/01/22">
         <title>Python</title>
         <value>25.5</value>
      </date>
   </shop>
</transactions>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am executing the xsl file inside notepad++, but there is an error. "Unable to apply transformation on current source. Make sure that XSL is valid."

Comment: I can't understand the note 2, can you give me a sample?

Comment: Read here why your method of grouping is "very inefficient": http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: I'm not sure npp xmltools is able to run xslt this way. Do you have anything beside npp?

Comment: @PavelKoryakin Thank you, I've solved this problem!

Comment: @michael.hor257k I realize that this method is relatively inefficient, but our xml file is not very large, it does not reflect the inefficiency. Later I will learn how to use key to solve this problem for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you manage to run it with npp? If yes, how?

Comment: @PavelKoryakin I ran the code with npp and the result was correct. :)

Comment: Can you please make a screenshot of how you set parameters in npp? I've tried but without success.