# XSLT Find element value that does not exist in siblings

Tags: xpath, xslt

I hava a list of elements A:

```
    <a sign="0">100<a/>
    <a sign="1">150<a/>
    <a sign="2">200<a/>
    <a sign="0">250<a/>
    <a sign="3">100<a/>
```

and another list of elements B:

```
    <b>
      <sign>1</sign>
      <sign>3</sign>
    </b>
    <b></b> <!--   no sign    -->
```

First, for each < b >, I want to sum up all < a > values that have the same sign then b. I do this with recursion:

```
<xsl:template name="sumCount">
    <xsl:param name="nodes" /> <!--   the a elements    -->
    <xsl:param name="signs"/>  <!--   the signs of the b element    -->
    <xsl:param name="tempSum" select="0" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$nodes and $signs">
            <xsl:variable name="countSum" select="sum($nodes[@sign=$signs[1]])" />
            <xsl:call-template name="sumItems">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes" />
                <xsl:with-param name="tempSum" select="number($tempSum) + number($countSum)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="signs" select="$signs[position() > 1]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tempSum" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

But now, if < b > has no signs, I want to find the sum all elements from A **which have not a sign that is a sign of one of the sibblings of my actual < b > node**. (Simply said, I want to find exactly all other nodes, that will not be picked up by the first summarize).

So in this example, for the second < b > with no sign, I would want to find < a > with sign 0 and 2 (and all other numbers other then 1 and 3).
I could select all other < b > nodes, but then I would need something like:

```
select="sum($nodes[@sign *not in* $otherBNodes)"
```

IS there something like this in xslt 1.0? How can I achieve this?

---

Edit: As the original answer does not solve my problem completly, but answered the question correctly, I will add the extending context here.

The problem is that my < a > nodes are not written in the root xml, but generated in the xsl and then made accessable by ext:node-set. I did edit your answer to demonstrate this.

**XML:**

```
<root>
<b id="1">
    <sign>1</sign>
    <sign>3</sign>
</b>
<b id="2"/>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
            exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name = "cNodes">
        <xsl:element name="a">
            <xsl:attribute name="sign"><xsl:value-of select="1"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="100"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="a">
            <xsl:attribute name="sign">
                <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="2"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="150"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="a">
            <xsl:attribute name="sign"><xsl:value-of select="3"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="200"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="a">
            <xsl:attribute name="sign"><xsl:value-of select="4"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="250"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:for-each select="ext:node-set(a)"> <!-- switch context-->
        <xsl:key name="a" match="a" use="@sign" />
        <xsl:variable name="all_a" select="a" />
        <xsl:copy>
                <b id="1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('a', 1))"/> <!-- I did not think about how to bring b here yet, so I take 1 for now-->
                </b>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Of course this does not work, while I can iterate over the < a > nodes, I somehow cannot create the key.

Comment: How many `b` elements can there be?

Comment: THis xpath would sum 0 and 2 elements regardless of the empty b `sum(//a[not(@sign = //b/sign)])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a radically different approach:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <a sign="0">100</a>
    <a sign="1">150</a>
    <a sign="2">200</a>
    <a sign="0">250</a>
    <a sign="3">100</a>
    <b id="1">
        <sign>1</sign>
        <sign>3</sign>
    </b>
    <b id="2"/>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="a" match="a" use="@sign" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="all_a" select="a" />
    <xsl:variable name="matched_a" select="key('a', b/sign)" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="b">
            <b id="{@id}">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="sign">
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('a', sign))"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum($all_a) - sum($matched_a)"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </b>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <b id="1">250</b>
   <b id="2">550</b>
</root>
```

---

### Added:

If you really need to create the `a` elements by hard-coding them inside the stylesheet, consider something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="a" match="a" use="@sign" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="a-rtf">
        <a sign="0">100</a>
        <a sign="1">150</a>
        <a sign="2">200</a>
        <a sign="0">250</a>
        <a sign="3">100</a>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="a-set" select="exsl:node-set($a-rtf)" />
    <xsl:variable name="all_signs" select="b/sign" />
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="b">
            <b id="{@id}">
                <xsl:variable name="sign" select="sign" />
                <!-- switch context to the variable document -->
                <xsl:for-each select="$a-set">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$sign">
                            <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('a', $sign))"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="sum($a-set/a) - sum(key('a', $all_signs))"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </b>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I did not know about this possibility yet :) There is one problem though, my example is a bit simplyfied. I get my nodes <a> as a nodeset, and as I learned from some other post from you, I cannot use a key lookup on < a > when I am in a <for-each> of < b >. Do you hava a solution for this problem?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by *"I get my nodes <a> as a nodeset"*.

Comment: The <a> elements are generated by me and therefore given to the template via ext:node-set($all_a). So if I understood right, I need to get into this new document context, I am trying to achieve this by doing a <xsl:for-each> on my $all_a var. But my key <xsl:key name="a_by_sign" match="a" use="@sign"/> does not select anything. Maybe beause my for-each already iterates through the <a>'s? I tried <xsl:key name="a_by_sign" match="../a" use="@sign"/> but no success

Comment: *״The <a> elements are generated by me"* Please edit your question and show this part in your stylesheet.

Comment: I added the additional context

Comment: Sorry, this is still not a reproducible problem. You show an `a` element being  created for each [something we cannot see]. Where is this something and why can't you refer to it directly?

Comment: I thought it is not necessary, will the result not always be just a list of elements < a > that is writen to the variable a_nodes? And if you make those elements accesible via ext:node-set($a_nodes), does it matter how or where it was created? In my understanding, this will be treated as a seperate document. Please correct me if i am wrong here. The for-each phrase that I did cut is iterating through a completly different set of elements, reading some values and writing them into the < a > element.

Comment: The point is that the variable you are creating is indeed a separate document, which complicates things because in XSLT 1.0 keys work only in the current document. So if you insist on going that route, you will need to store the `sign` elements of the current `b` in a variable, switch the context to the other document, and call the key using the variable (see just one example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32440143/3016153). OTOH, if you point the key to the original nodes, you can avoid all that jazz. It looks like there is a 1-to-1 relation between them, so I don't see why you wouldn't.

Comment: I am afraid I will have to stick to those node-sets... But I still dont get it somehow. I did try to switch context with <for-each select=ext:node-set($cNodes)>and while I can iterate through my a_nodes, my key <xsl:key name="a" match="a" use="@sign"/> does not work. I did edit once more the second part of my question, I would be really thankfull if u could take a look once more

Comment: See if the added version makes sense. I still suspect this is overcomplicating things.

Comment: I tried everything but the key function in you example always returns 0 for me. I tried pretty much the same yesterday for my document with the same results. I do agree that this is probably to complicated, but those elements are written in legacy code, and I would rather like to not touch those...

Comment: I tested my answer with same input as before (minus the `a` elements) and the result is the same as before. I am afraid I don't know how to help you with a problem I cannot reproduce.

Comment: Oh my... looks like the IntelliJ transformation runs short here. I tested it within a web solution and it works fine. Thanks for going all the way with me, it really helped me a lot!